# CORS Error in Laravel 7 using Laravel Lighthouse

Tags: laravel, graphql, cors, vue-apollo, laravel-lighthouse

I have an API built with Laravel and Lighthouse-php(for GraphQL). My client is built with Vue js and uses Apollo for the graphQL client-side implementation. Anytime I make a request, I get the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Naturally, I proceeded to install laravel-cors package but I realized afterwards that it came by default with my Laravel installation (7.2.2). Which meant that `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class` was already added to the middleware array in `Kernel.php` and the cors config file was already in my config directory.

After some googling, I realized that I needed to add `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class` to the `route.middleware` array in my `config/lighthouse.php` file

It still did not work. I have restarted the server, cleared cache, cleared config and run `composer dump-autoload` but I still get the error. I have no idea how to get past this. Any help will be appreciated.

**Versions**

Laravel 7.2.2

Laravel Lighthouse 4.10

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got some help from the folks at lighthouse [here](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/issues/1266). The problem was with my cors configuration. I needed to add `graphql` to the path array in config/cors but I mistakenly added `graphql/*`. So the path array looked like this

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'graphql/*'],
```

instead of this

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'graphql'],
```

After making the changes, I run the following:
`php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan config:clear` and `composer dump-autoload` before the CORS error was gone.

The full configuration that worked for me was

```
return [
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'graphql'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => false,
    'max_age' => false,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
];
```